# How to assign new column based on the list of string values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, feature-engineering

I have a dataframe that one of the column contains string values, and I want to assign new column if this column values are in the list I specified.

my_list = ['AA', 'TR', 'NZ']

For example:
My dataframe : df

| country |
| --- |
| AA |
| TR |
| SG |

The dataframe I want to have:

| country | flag |
| --- | --- |
| AA | 1 |
| TR | 1 |
| SG | 0 |

I tried this one but I gave an Value Error.

```
df.assign(flag = lambda df: '1' if df['country'].isin(my_list) else '0')
```

What should I do? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly convert your boolean to 0/1 with [`astype(int)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df.assign(flag= df['country'].isin(my_list).astype(int))
```

Or for a string:

```
df.assign(flag= df['country'].isin(my_list).astype(int).astype(str))
```

Alternatively, use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
import numpy as np
df.assign(flag=np.where(df['country'].isin(my_list), '1', '0'))
```

output:

```
  country flag
0      AA    1
1      TR    1
2      SG    0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

my_list = ['AA', 'TR', 'NZ']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Country", "Flag"])

df.loc[0] = ["AA", 0]
df.loc[1] = ["TR", 0]
df.loc[2] = ["SG", 0]

print(df)

for i in range(len(df)):
    if df["Country"].iloc[i] in my_list:
        df["Flag"].iloc[i] = 1

print(df)
```

Comment: You should almost never have to loop with pandas, this is an anti-pattern! Also using `in my_list` repeatedly is quadratic complexity.